# How to overcome the error `Specify a guest user’s nickname for the guestUser field`?

Tags: unlocked-package, sharing-rule

We are trying to put Sharing Rule into unlocked package to share access to the Knowledge records using Sharing Rules and we receive the following error:

```
Details: Knowledge__kav.GuestUserAccessToKnowledge: Specify a guest user’s nickname for the guestUser field.
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately `SharingGuestRule` and well as other Sharing Rules are not supported by unlocked packages

[image]

So we shouldn't try to put it inside an unlocked package but rather deploy it using unpackaged metadata API deployment.